# Tkinter change data

Tags: python, tkinter

i wanna change the data, just switch some pixels to white or black, but i dont get it working that i can change the data ? When i use the line np.roll() it rolls the image and updates it very fast, but when i use any other method of simply changing the values of the data-array, i fail ?

what should i do, what do i wrong ?

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy
import time

times=1
timestart=time.clock()
data=numpy.array(numpy.random.random((68,68))*100,dtype=int)
#data = numpy.zeros([68,68])
photo = None
sw = 1

def image_loop():
        global data
        global times
        global timestart
        global photo

        im=Image.fromstring('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
        canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
        root.update()
        times+=1
        if times%33==0:
                print "%.02f FPS"%(times/(time.clock()-timestart))

        root.after(100,image_loop)
        ### THE next line WORKS, why not the others ???????
        #data=numpy.roll(data,-1,1)


        ### Does not work ??
        global sw
        if sw == 0:
                for i in range(68):
                        data[10][i] * 100
                        #data = numpy.array(numpy.zeros(68,68))
                sw = 1
                print "hi"
        else:
                sw = 0
                for i in range(68):
                        data[10][i] / 100
                        data = numpy.array(numpy.ones(68,68))
                        #data = data * 100
                print "ho"



root = Tkinter.Tk()
frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, width=68, height=68)
frame.pack()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(frame, width=68,height=68)
canvas.place(x=-2,y=-2)

root.after(0,image_loop) # INCREASE THE 0 TO SLOW IT DOWN
#root.mainloop()

while True:
        print "do work again and again, change data"
        root.update()
        root.update_idletasks()


        print data.shape
```

Answer (score 2):

The thing was to not init the data var randomly at init. This code works with 95 Frames per second

```
import Tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import numpy
import time

times=1
timestart=time.clock()
data = None
photo = None

sw = 1

def image_loop():
        global data
        global times
        global timestart
        global photo

        im=Image.fromstring('L', (data.shape[1],data.shape[0]), data.astype('b').tostring())
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
        canvas.create_image(0,0,image=photo,anchor=Tkinter.NW)
        root.update()
        times+=1
        if times%33==0:
                print "%.02f FPS"%(times/(time.clock()-timestart))

        root.after(10,image_loop)



root = Tkinter.Tk()
frame = Tkinter.Frame(root, width=68, height=68)
frame.pack()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(frame, width=68,height=68)
canvas.place(x=-2,y=-2)

root.after(0,image_loop)

data=numpy.array(numpy.random.random((68,68))*100,dtype=int)


while True:
        #print "do work again and again, change data"
        root.update()
        root.update_idletasks()

        global sw
        if sw == 0:
                for i in range(68):
                        data[10][i] = 250
                sw = 1
        else:
                sw = 0
                for i in range(68):
                        data[10][i] = 0
"plot.py" 58L, 1190C                                                                                                                                                                       1,1           Top
```

Comment: Instead of calling `create_image` in the loop, you can't probably just reconfigure an existing canvas image object. As written, you've got a bit of a memory leak because you create 100 image objects per second on the canvas and never destroy the old ones. The canvas may start to have performance issues once you've created a few thousand images. Otherwise, this is a nice solution!

Comment: hi @BryanOakley  what do you mean, with "you can't reconfigure an existing canvas"  ?  I dont create 100 images, its an array of 68x68 and the values of the array are multiplied with 100, to see the pixels as white in the image.  I run this code now with more than 100 million images and i got no memory increase.    I dont destroy the old one, i simply override it

Comment: Argh! That's a typo. I meant to say "you **can** probably just reconfigure...". I think I started to write "why can't you..." and then changed it around. Mea culpa. The memory leak will be small, but it exists. The garbage collector handles the memory of the image ok, but every time you call `create_image` the underlying tcl/tk code creates a new canvas object that never gets destroyed.

Comment: ok, and 100 million is also a typo which i cannot correct since SO dont allow editing this comment anymore ?? i mean 10 million, but its running for hours very well